# LotusScript GetFirstDocument function returns Nothing (ver 8.5.3)

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a domino agent which reads the inbox view. After debugging I find that it is not able to traverse the documents inside $inbox, even though there are documents inside it . So basically  inbox.GetFirstDocument returns "Nothing".  So is this the index problem?. Surprisingly I find that after a long delay(eg. a day after), this problem goes away and the while loop to process documents works fine. So I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Can you provide more info about What kind of agent you have (predelivery/scheduled/etc.)?

Comment: Yes basically the agent is a scheduled agent which keeps on running  after few minutes each. And this is a cluster which consists of two domino servers. And added to that the "Inbox" of the other server in cluster is always empty, and replication does not work !. Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to add there were no code changes, and we saw the problems few days back.The agent was working fine previously. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot post the code here, but the while loop which processes the inbox documents, also removes it: document.RemoveFromFolder("($Inbox)".

Comment: Without code -> no help

Comment: Is this post related to [this ServerFault- question](http://serverfault.com/questions/611905/lotus-notes-inbox-issue/612620#612620)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a case where a rogue Inbox folder has been created in one or both of the replicas of the database. That would explain why replication doesn't appear to work --because you're actually looking at different folders, both of which happen to be named Inbox.

Check in Domino Designer on both replicas. Do you see more than one folder named "Inbox", "$Inbox" or "$(Inbox)"? If there's more than one, find the "real" inbox -- i.e., the one that the router delivers to. Delete the rest of the inbox folders, and replicate. Note that it is possible to have different "real" inboxes in each replica, in which case you would want to merge the contents of both folders before deleting anything.